# div não respeita tamanho definido no css

Tags: html, css, div

Estou tentando criar um sistema de mensagens, mas a formatação da div não está respeitando o tamanho. Gostaria que me ajudassem, para saber aonde estou errando:

```css
#limit {
  max-width: 500px;
}


#table-overflow {
  max-height:400px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}



#targetDiv{
  /* ... */

  position: absolute;
  top:      1000;
  bottom:   0;
  left:     0;
  right:    0;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* .
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- FACEBOOK META-TAGS -->

<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi//0.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="http://http://paulosergioduff.atspace.cc/cpu.php"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="">

<!-- faceapp  -->

<!-- O jQuery NÃO é necessário para utilização do SDK Javascript do Facebook. Incluí por utilizar em outra parte deste exemplo -->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="index.php">Live JSON</a><img src="img/jasonmask31x31.png">
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">

        </ul></div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br>
<hr>

</hr>

<div class="container-narrow" >

  <div class="masthead">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="caixaentrada.php">Mensagens</a></li>
      <li><a href="config.php">Meu perfil</a></li>
      <li><a href="dev.php">Desenvolvimento</a></li>     
    </ul><br>
    <h3 class="muted">O que tem a oferecer ao mundo?</h3>
  </div>
  <center >
    <form action="cpu.php" method="GET">
      <!--Usuário:
<select name="user" >
<option value="ceaed6e06da7162089094ab24b33905fd5a78f88">ceaed6e06da7162089094ab24b33905fd5a78f88</option> 
</select><br> -->
      Mensagem:
      <textarea name="menssage"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="Enviar sinal" class="btn btn-large btn-success">
      <hr>

      <div id='limit' align='left'>
        <hr>
        <img src='img/ceaed6e06da7162089094ab24b33905fd5a78f88.jpg' width='31' height='31' />
        <div aling='left'id='limit' >
          novo banco<hr></div><div id='limit' align='left'><hr><img src='img/ceaed6e06da7162089094ab24b33905fd5a78f88.jpg' width='31' height='31' />
        <div aling='left'id='limit' >
          novo teste<hr></div><div id='limit' align='left'><hr><img src='img/ceaed6e06da7162089094ab24b33905fd5a78f88.jpg' width='31' height='31' />
        <div aling='left'id='limit' >
          dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<hr></div><div id='limit' align='left'><hr><img src='img/ceaed6e06da7162089094ab24b33905fd5a78f88.jpg' width='31' height='31' />
        <div aling='left'id='limit' >
          dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<hr></div><div id='limit' align='left'><hr><img src='img/ceaed6e06da7162089094ab24b33905fd5a78f88.jpg' width='31' height='31' />
        <div aling='left'id='limit' >
          dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<hr></div><div id='limit' align='left'><hr><img src='img/jasonmask31x31.jpg' width='31' height='31' />
        <div aling='left'id='limit' >
          <hr></div><a href='downloadfile.php'>Baixar conversa</a>
```

Comment: Tente adicionar `word-break:break-all;` no css da div. Não sou especialista em web/css, mas achei essa dica [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763482/text-not-wrapping-inside-a-div-element), e pareceu funcionar. Talvez não seja a solução ideal neste caso.

Comment: Esse link analisa a sintaxe HTML http://www.billauer.co.il/html_highlighting_nesting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua marcação não esta correta

```
height='31
```

Sempre que abrir aspas você precisa fechar, sugiro usar uma IDE como sublime ou qualquer outra para facilitar a leitura do codigo.

```
height='31px'
```

Comment: Eu corrigi, mas o problema persistiu. Basicamente está acontecendo naquela div que está o texto com "ddddd......" até preencher a tela.
Não consigo achar a falha!

Comment: Eu consegui solucionar! Faltava fechar uma div no navbar. 
Desde já obrigado!